# Selection in GroupBy query with NHibernate with dynamic anonymous object

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, nhibernate, reflection.emit

My main objective is to create a dynamic group by and use it in NHibernate.

Consider this non dynamic example that **works**:

```
_repository.Collection<User>().GroupBy(u => new { u.Active }).Select(s => s.Key, Count = s.Count())
```

Now, I create a dynamic object to generate the `new { u.Active }` part dynamically:

```
    private Expression<Func<T, object>> CreateGrouping<T>(IEnumerable<string> by)
    {
        var dynamicTypeForGroup = GetDynamicTypeForGroup<T>(by);
        var sourceItem = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        var bindings = dynamicTypeForGroup
            .GetFields()
            .Select(p => Expression.Bind(p, Expression.PropertyOrField(sourceItem, p.Name)))
            .Cast<MemberBinding>()
            .ToArray();
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Convert(
            Expression.MemberInit(
                Expression.New(dynamicTypeForGroup.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)),
                bindings),
            dynamicTypeForGroup),
        sourceItem);
    }
```

The type is generated in method `GetDynamicTypeForGroup` and then instantiated with `Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(dynamicTypeForGroup.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)), bindings)`

This is how the Type is generated:

```
    private Type GetDynamicTypeForGroup<T>(IEnumerable<string> members)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var dynamicAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
            new AssemblyName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave
        );
        var dynamicModule = dynamicAssembly.DefineDynamicModule(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        var typeBuilder = dynamicModule.DefineType(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        var properties = members.Select(prop => type.GetProperty(ObjectExtensions.NormilizePropertyName(prop)))
                            .Where(prop => prop != null)
                            .Cast<MemberInfo>();

        var fields = properties
            .Select(property => typeBuilder.DefineField(
                property.Name,
                ((PropertyInfo)property).PropertyType,
                FieldAttributes.Public
            )).Cast<FieldInfo>()
            .ToArray();

        GenerateEquals(typeBuilder, fields);
        GenerateGetHashCode(typeBuilder, fields);

        return typeBuilder.CreateType();
    }
```

---

## SO, THE PROBLEM

If I use `_repository.Collection<User>().GroupBy(u => new { u.Active })` it works, but if I add the Select part - `.Select(s => s.Key, Count = s.Count())` (or any select statment) I got the following **NotSupportedException: MemberInit**

> System.NotSupportedException: MemberInit
>      em NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression) (ommited)

My doubt is:

- I know that NHibernate supports a Select statement with a *group by* and an anonymous type, but why it can't suport the Select if this type was created with the Expression Tree?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently NHibernate LINQ query translator does not support `MemberInitExpression` in `GroupBy` selector.

But why anonymous type works? Because although expression `new { Active = u.Active }` syntactically *looks like* `MemberInitExpression` (class initializer), in fact it isn't!

What C# compiler generates (and NHibernate supports) is a call to a *constructor with parameters* ([NewExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.newexpression?view=netframework-4.8)) mapped to class members through [Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.newexpression.members?view=netframework-4.8) property - the third argument of the following [Expression.New](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.new?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_New_System_Reflection_ConstructorInfo_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Reflection_MemberInfo__) overload:

```
public static NewExpression New (
    ConstructorInfo constructor,
    IEnumerable<Expression> arguments,
    IEnumerable<MemberInfo> members
)
```

Which is the solution of the problem. Inside your dynamic type builder, generate a constructor with parameters matching the fields (and assign the corresponding fields inside the body):

```
var fields = properties
    .Select(property => typeBuilder.DefineField(
        property.Name,
        ((PropertyInfo)property).PropertyType,
        FieldAttributes.Public
    )).Cast<FieldInfo>()
    .ToArray();

GenerateConstructor(typeBuilder, fields); // <--

GenerateEquals(typeBuilder, fields);
GenerateGetHashCode(typeBuilder, fields);

return typeBuilder.CreateType();
```

and then use something like this:

```
private Expression<Func<T, object>> CreateGrouping<T>(IEnumerable<string> by)
{
    var keyType = GetDynamicTypeForGroup<T>(by);
    var sourceItem = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var members = keyType.GetFields();
    var arguments = members.Select(m => Expression.PropertyOrField(sourceItem, m.Name));
    var constructor = keyType.GetConstructor(members.Select(m => m.FieldType).ToArray());
    var newKey = Expression.New(constructor, arguments, members);        
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(newKey, sourceItem);
}
```

Comment: Well, when I checked the NHibernate code for HqlGeneratorExpressionVisitor I noticed that both Expression.New and Member init were not Supported. 
https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Linq/Visitors/HqlGeneratorExpressionVisitor.cs#L96
Seems that NHibernate take a different way.. Anyway, Expression.new indeed worked :)